# Generic getter that returns Object of Child Class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Let's assume I have 3 classes: `Car`, `Convertible` and `Garage`.

`Car` is an abstract class that `Convertible` inherits from:

Convertible has one specific method called `unfoldRoof()`.

`Garage` contains one `Car` with the following `getCar()` method:

```
public Car getCar() {
    return car;
}
```

When accessing the `Car` attribute over the getter, I cannot use the specific `Convertible` method `unfoldRoof()`.

How can I build a **generic** getter that returns the **child class** and not the **abstract parent class**?

Comment: 1. You could just have it return a Convertible instead of a Car. 2. What happens if the Car *isnt* a Convertible and doesn't have that method?

Comment: If you are sure it's a Convertible you could also cast the result to a Convertible and call the unfoldRoof(). Or check if it's actually a Convertible before casting (with instanceof).

Comment: @KostasStamos, I would prefer to keep it generic though, since I will need to implement further child classes of Car.

Comment: If they are to be subclasses of Convertible, then you could still use them as Convertible object. If they are just siblings of Convertible, they would not have the unfoldRoof() method, so Java helps you by prohibiting you from calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a capability, so use Optional:

```
class Car {
    <C extends Car> Optional<C> as(Class<C> type) {
        return type.isInstance(this)
                ? Optional.of(type.cast(this))
                : Optional.empty();
    }
}

Car car = new Convertible();

car.as(Convertible.class).ifPresent(convertible -> {
    convertible.unfoldRoof();
});
```

---

*By the way*. Inheritance Car/Convertible *in General* is not really needed, you could have Interfaces like

```
Interface Convertible {
    void unfoldRoof();
}
```

However that would require installing Features/capabilities in a map field or such.

Answer (score 1):

**Run-time specific type from general interface**

You can specify an extended return type generically

```
public abstract Car <CarType extends Car>{
  public abstract CarType getTypedCar();
}
```

... then ...

```
public class Convertable extends Car<Convertable> {
  public <Convertable> getTypedCar(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

but you would still need to know what type you were getting when you did `getTypedCar()` i.e.

```
Convertable convertable = car.getTypedCar();
```

and it would be the same (as far as run-time type safety goes) as not generifying it and writing

```
 Convertable convertable = (Convertable)car;
```

**Run-time specific type from container holding interface instances**

The problem comes when you want the `Garage` to know the run-time type of the `Car` it's holding.  You want it to hold any `Car` but you want it to return the specific type at run-time, which it doesn't know at compile-time so can only be defined to return objects as specific as what it is holding; in this case, `Car`.
You could get around this by making the `Garage` only hold `Convertables` like @Valentin Ruano suggest but in real life, that's a silly thought as your objects can't represent real world objects as they are supposed to.  i.e. can you build a Garage that only takes convertibles?!

**Your needs**

It all depends on your needs.  For example, do you NEED to know what type a car is to remove it from the `Garage`?  Or could you just return `Car` then use the solution above to do `getTypedCar()`?  Again, you would need to know (assume) the type of car to do this but that will need to happen in this design somewhere in order to be flexible.

Another place to put this assumption would be on the getter of the `Garage`, you could have a method `getCar(Class carType)` and have it throw a `NoSuchCarException` if the desired car type isn't there, otherwise return a type of `carType`.

Comment: I think he means that the ```Garage``` has a car field and getter not that the car has a getter to itself or some other car of the same type.

Comment: I see.  Answer expanded although in essence, it's unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You could define unfoldRoof() for car that just returns, doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is to make `Garage` generic:

```
abstract class Car {
    String make();
    int year();
    //...
}

class Convertible extends Car {
    void unfoldRoof() { /* whatever */ }
}

class Garage<C extends Car> {

   private C car = null;

   public Garage() {}

   public boolean isEmpty()  { return car == null; }

   public C getCar() { return car; }

   public void park(final C car) {
       if (!isEmpty()) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Garage is full!!");
       } else {
          this.car = car;
       }
   }

   public C exit() {
       if (isEmpty()) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no cars in garage");
       } else {
         final C exitingCar = car;
         car = null;
         return exitingCar;
       }
   }
}

class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      final Garage<Convertible> myGarage = new Garage();
      final Convertible car = ...;
      myGarage.park(car);

      //...

      car = myGarage.getCar();
      car.unfoldRoof();
   }

}
```